# How to list all the pods running in a particular worker node by executing a command from master?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, bare-metal-server

I need to get the list of pods running in a worker node by executing a command from master node. I can achieve if i moved into the worker node and execute `kubectl get pods -n ns`. But i need to execute this from the master node and get pods in worker.

Answer (score 13):

You can get pods running on specific node by using this command:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=<node>
```

This will list all pods from all namespaces but you can narrow it down for specific namespace.

Answer (score 7):

Running `kubectl get pods -n ns` in a specific node does not give the pods running in that node, rather it will give all pods in namespace `ns` regardless of which nodes they run.`kubectl get pods -n ns -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=<nodename>` gives the pods in `ns` namespace deployed in a particular node. This command can be executed from any nodes or from a system which has access to the cluster.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=kind-control-plane
```

To get pods from all namespaces running in a particular node use command

```
kubectl get pods -A -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=<nodename>
```

You can also use `kubectl describe nodes nodename` and check `Non-terminated Pods` section to view which pods are currently running in that particular node.

```
kubectl describe nodes kind-control-plane

PodCIDRs:                     10.244.0.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (9 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                          CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                          ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 coredns-6955765f44-ftkv6                      100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (3%)        170Mi (8%)     56m
  kube-system                 coredns-6955765f44-wgkbn                      100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (3%)        170Mi (8%)     56m
  kube-system                 etcd-kind-control-plane                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         56m
  kube-system                 kindnet-248xd                                 100m (5%)     100m (5%)   50Mi (2%)        50Mi (2%)      56m
  kube-system                 kube-apiserver-kind-control-plane             250m (12%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         56m
  kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-kind-control-plane    200m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         56m
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-n4ntb                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         56m
  kube-system                 kube-scheduler-kind-control-plane             100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         56m
  local-path-storage          local-path-provisioner-7745554f7f-wgnwm       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         56m
Allocated resources:
```

Comment: Thanks @Arghya.This would help me find the number of pods running in each node. So, there is no separate command to find pods in a particular node?

Comment: I have updated the answer with another command which can give you that information